# Palindrome numbers made from the product of two 3-digit numbers

Tags: java

I have been trying to create a program in Java to print all Palindrome numbers made from the product of two 3-digit numbers. But somehow the program is not giving any output. Here is my code:

```
public class Lessons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      int a;
      int b;
      int c;
      int r;


      for (a=100; a<1000;a++)
      {
       for (b=100; b<1000; b++)
       {
           c= a*b;
           int l;
           r=0;
           while (c>0){
             l = c%10;
             r = r*10+l;
             c = c/10;               
           }
           if (r==c)
           {
               System.out.println("The Palindrome number are:");
               System.out.println(r);

           }

        }}}}
```

Any helps???

Comment: When I run it, no output is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store `c` into another variable because you are changing it in the `while` loop. Alternatively, change

```
if (r==c)
```

to

```
if (r==a*b)
```

but that is less efficient because in that case each multiplication is performed twice.

By the way, an optimization that should be done is to change second `for` loop to:

```
for (b=a; b<1000; b++) { .. }
```

This way you are avoiding calculating each product two times.

Comment: I got the required Palindrome list by making this change. Can you please tell me how do I get the largest Palindrome number out of my output list???

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal Largest palindrome number is obviously the one printed last. If you want to return it, add an additional variable, let's call it `max`, where you will store that number. `max` should be updated within `if` clause.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance one of the things I'm seeing, is that you are dividing c/10 while its bigger than 0, but since c is an int, the last time it gets divided, it will be 0 at the end of the loop, and since r is increasing at the end of the loop, they are never gonna have the same value, hence why you aren't getting any output.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n,i,j;
    for(i=100;i<200;i++)
        {
        for(j=100;j<200;j++)
            {
             int r,sum=0,temp; 
               n=i*j;
               temp=n;    
              while(n>0){    
               r=n%10; 
              sum=(sum*10)+r;    
               n=n/10;  

         } 
       if(temp==sum)    
         System.out.println(temp); 

            }

        }
```